# How to communicate between server and client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express, next.js

How to send request to server from client, client is next.js and server is express.js.

I am trying to implement google auth, on server I have routes which will redirect me to google auth:

AuthController class on Server:

```
export default class AuthenticationController {
  public static async authGoogle(
    req: Express.Request,
    res: Express.Response,
    next: () => void
  ): Promise<void> {
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] })(
      req,
      res,
      next
    );
  }

  public static async authGoogleCallback(
    req: Express.Request,
    res: Express.Response
  ): Promise<void> {
    passport.authenticate('google', {}, (err, user: User) => {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      if (err) {
        logger.error('Login failed', err, JSON.stringify(user));
        res.status(500);
        res.send({
          message: 'Login failed',
          success: false
        });
      } else {
        logger.debug(`User ${user.id} logged in`);
        res.status(200);
        res.cookie('jwt', 1);
        res.send({
          message: 'User logged in',
          success: true,
          token: `${jsonwebtoken.sign(
            JSON.stringify(user),
            process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'DONT_USE_IN_PROD'
          )}`
        });
        res.redirect('/');
      }
      res.end();
    })(req, res);
  }
```

This is Authentication Router on server:

```
export function authenticationRouter(): Router {
  const router = Router();

export function addGoogleRoutes(router: Router): Router {
  // Google auth routes
  router.get('/google', AuthenticationController.authGoogle);
  router.get('/google/callback', AuthenticationController.authGoogleCallback);

  return router;
}
```

Main problem is that, I don't undrstand how to access to server, how to send request, and execute routes google route `(addGoogleRoutes)` on server from Login component.

This is Login component/page on client in next.js:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    return {};
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('handle click');
    fetch.post('point google auth route on server');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <LoginLayout title="Login Page">
        <button className="login-field" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Login with Google
        </button>
      </LoginLayout>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Any advice or help is welcome!

Comment: Note: If you post something in client side ``fetch.post`` it has to be ``router.post`` in your server, not ``router.get``

Comment: @josemartindev ok, yup, I am will use then get. Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand. Next.js is already acting as a server (server-side rendering of React components is the main reason to use Next). If you want to customize the server side, you have to do it from within the framework, see https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-server-and-routing